# How can I change the Google search box back to its smaller size?

Tags: safari

I can't stand the new Google search box (and buttons). I feel they're extremely over-sized and I would love to revert them back to their former selves.

[image]

How can I do this on Safari 4? I'm aware of Stylish for Firefox, but Stylish themes don't seem to work with Safari.

Comment: I totally agree. The new google search is like for people 95 and older with eye problems. How do you fix this in FF?

Comment: huh, I thought i was going crazy when it got bigger. Good to know that i am not crazy...

Comment: Or you can just get used to it. You won't even notice it a couple of days or weeks in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install [this greasmonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/57449) to undo it.

Comment: Is greasemonkey available for safari 4?

Comment: +1 for saving me from poking my eye out with a sharp character (FF user here)... 

for safari I found this: http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/11/14/how-to-run-greasemonkey-scripts-in-safari/ 
check comments for safari 4 compatibility, didn't test it though since I don't use it

Comment: Works well but stretches the page a little. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could [create a user stylesheet](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/ht/htcssusersafari.htm) for Safari with the lines:

```
input.lst { 
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  }
input.lsb {
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 0
  }
```

Might also need to add something like:  `width:25em`  to  `input.lst`  if the search box is still too wide.